# MAX Date grouping improperly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

```
SELECT
    ij.IJITEM AS Part,
    ij.IJLOC AS Location,
    ib.IFQOH AS QOH,
    MAX(ij.IJDATE) AS Inv_Date
FROM
    dbo.S2K_IJALL ij
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S2K_IB ib 
    ON ib.IFITEM = ij.IJITEM AND ib.IFLOC = ij.IJLOC
WHERE
    IJITEM LIKE '%-IC'
AND
    IJRBAL < 0
GROUP BY
    ij.IJITEM,
    ij.IJLOC,
    ib.IFQOH
```

I need to add a field to the query above.  When I do, the MAX date field does not maintain.  I get every record where the added field has a value.  How can I just pull back the value for that field for the MAX date?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Join the query above to the table that contains the new field on the key field(s) as well as IJDate = Inv_Date, which is in fact the MAX(IJDATE). Select all the fields from the first query as well as the new field.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle ties.  The field I need to add to the SELECT is IJRBAL.  I need that most current value for that field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more columns that you want to add and the result gets screwy when you `GROUP BY`, you can alter the query to use a subquery:

```
select ij.IJITEM AS Part,
  ij.IJLOC AS Location,
  ib.IFQOH AS QOH,
  ij2.ijdate Inv_date,
  --- add other columns
from dbo.S2K_IJALL ij1
inner join
(
  select MAX(IJDATE) ijdate, IJITEM, IJLOC
  from dbo.S2K_IJALL
  WHERE IJITEM LIKE '%-IC'
    AND IJRBAL < 0
  group by IJITEM, IJLOC
) ij2
  on ij1.ijdate = ij2.ijdate
  and ij1.IJITEM = ij2.IJITEM
  and ij1.IJLOC = ij2.IJLOC
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S2K_IB ib 
  ON ib.IFITEM = ij1.IJITEM 
  AND ib.IFLOC = ij1.IJLOC
WHERE ij1.IJITEM LIKE '%-IC'
  AND ij1.IJRBAL < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or newer (please always specify your version!):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT
    ij.IJITEM AS Part,
    ij.IJLOC AS Location,
    ib.IFQOH AS QOH,

    -- any other non-grouping column(s) can go here,

    ij.IJDATE AS Inv_date,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
      ij.IJITEM, ij.IJLOC, ib.IFQOH ORDER BY ij.IJDATE DESC)
  FROM
    dbo.S2K_IJALL ij
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S2K_IB ib 
    ON ib.IFITEM = ij.IJITEM AND ib.IFLOC = ij.IJLOC
  WHERE IJITEM LIKE '%-IC'
  AND IJRBAL < 0
)
SELECT Part, Location, QOH, Inv_date
  FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

You may need to tell us how you want to handle ties, there could be multiple rows with the same grouping and the same max(date) but with different values for the column(s) you want to add...